# How can I reset a combobox in a grid and set a new value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combobox in a grid with 2 options. The grid rows are editable and what I want is that after I update any value from the row selected the comobox get reset and set automatically a new value.

Ex.

If when inserting a new row I set the values as: name: Victor
Gender: male (this would be the combobox)

And when I am udating data after clicking twice directly in the row I chance the name to:

Name: jennifer
Gender: I WANT TO RESET THE VALUE AND SET THE SECOND OPTION AUTOATICALLY IN THE COMBOBOX

Inserting Data : This is how the data is sent to SP, it has 2 comboboxes one for gender F = FEMALE and M = MALE [IMAGE EXAMPLE Insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3jMZ.png)

But when I am updating directly on the row after clicking twice the data is sent to SP like this: [IMAGE EXAMPLE Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13hc0.png)

Updating is sending Description and not the code

Comment: Do you have snippet?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but this works out of the box: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2drv Also, no shouting please.

Comment: @Alexander I have edited my post so I can show you some pictures about my problem